# Is there a solution to run non-unicode (GBK) program in linux?

Tags: linux, encoding, gbk

I have a large C++ project that was originally developed on Windows for drawing, parsing, and processing drawings. Due to historical reasons, this project was initially designed to support GBK encoding only on Simplified Chinese systems. As a result, a significant number of resources such as drawings and configuration files are encoded in GBK.

Now, I want to run this project on Linux while maintaining compatibility with the existing drawings and other resource files. The program interacts with the Linux API, which expects UTF-8 encoding for reading and writing. I have tried performing encoding conversion in various places where character encoding is involved, but the workload is significant, and it is challenging to ensure complete internal encoding uniformity within the program.

Here is an abstract code to explain what my program wants to do：

```c
struct MySheet{
    char *gbkSubSheet;
    int otherAttributes;
};

int main()
{
    // Assuming this is a drawing sheet created by the user, which contains path information for some sub files
    // Due to historical reasons, these drawings stored path information in the form of C strings
    char subSheetFromUserInput[512] = "gbkPathOfSubSheet";
    MySheet mySheetFromWindow;
    mySheetFromWindow.gbkSubSheet = subSheetFromUserInput;

    // I want the same code to run properly on both Windows and Linux systems
    // Because the program must be compatible with existing drawings and able to cross platforms
    FILE* fp = fopen(mySheetFromWindow.gbkSubSheet, "r");
    /* ... read the sheet ... */
    fclose(fp);

    //===================================================

    // The following approach is not what I want
    // because there are many similar places in the code that require GBK encoding
    FILE* fp = fopen(gbkToUTF8(mySheetFromWindow.gbkSubSheet), "r");
    /* ... read the sheet ... */
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to make the program run in a GBK environment on Linux, where interfaces like fopen, access, mkdir, getcwd, and others related to character encoding api accept GBK encoding?

Comment: _"The program interacts with the Linux API, which expects UTF-8 encoding for reading and writing"_ Could you provide your source for this, or give an example of something your interfacing with that expects UTF-8 encoding? As a rule, Linux does not expect the user space to use any particular encoding.

Comment: See also [The kernel and character set encodings](https://lwn.net/Articles/71472/): "it is often said that UTF-8 is the encoding used by the Linux kernel. That statement is a mistake, however: Linux does not use any particular encoding. If user space uses UTF-8 to represent extended characters, everything will work. But nothing forces user space to work in that way."

Comment: How is the duplicate related to this question?

Comment: I added a piece of code in the question to explain my idea.

I know that Linux's file system does not strictly require an exact encoding. But for typical Linux systems, the file paths of user created files are saved in UTF-8 encoding, so when I want to use file IO interfaces to manipulate specific files, these interfaces usually require me to provide the correct file names in UTF-8 encoding.